# How can I edit my Windows 7 Pro hosts file, having logged in as administrator?

Tags: windows-7

I want to add a line into my hosts file to prevent access to the web domain `foo.bar`, which should be achievable with the line

```
127.0.0.1 foo.bar
```

But when I log in as an administrator the icon for the file shows a locked padlock. I can open it with Notepad but when I try to save it as "hosts" (not "hosts.txt") I get an "access denied" message. Yet the permissions say the administrator has "full control", and "Read-only" is unchecked.

How can I edit this file?

Comment: @Ramhound - Unfortunately, no. "hosts" is not showing as read-only; and "full control" is in the permissions for every user ("SYSTEM", "Administrators", and my usual user), although for each user "Special permissions" is not checked. I suspect the answer may lie somewhere under Security | Advanced.

Comment: As I said, it's not the solution - I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: In a comment to another answer, you indicate you were successful in modifying the hosts file, by running notepad as an Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Find Notepad. Right Click, Open as Administrator.

Navigate to the HOSTS file, open it, edit it, and save it.

Notepad needs to be Admin. This is different from being Windows Admin

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know the two admins were different. But I still can't do it. When I go "Open" in Notepad and select "All files" to get it to show up, it still shows with a padlock. I can then open it, change something in the content, and choose Save. It offers to save it as "hosts.txt", so I choose "All files" under "Save as Type" and then click Save to save it on top of "hosts", but it is saving as "hosts.txt" and leaving "hosts" unchanged.

Comment: Make sure in Windows Explorer that HOSTS has Read Only and Hidden unchecked. Make sure Windows Explorer options allow you to see Hidden Files. Then try again opening Notepad As Administrator. See if this helps you

Comment: Many thanks for this. Taking all those steps I can now see the line I added into "hosts", namely `127.0.0.1 foo.bar` but the problem has slipped around a bit because I can still browse to the unwanted site in Firefox. (And the icon for the hosts file is still appearing padlocked, FWIW.)